# Why can't access attribute in request?

Tags: struts2

I want to access some attributes in request, for example, the `base` attribute in request, 
the following are part of values in request

```
 request    ...base=/ecs, stack=com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack@11c4b31}, __cleanup_recursion_counter=1, .freemarker.RequestParameters=freemarker.ext.servlet.HttpRequestParametersHashModel@1c00cb4 ...
```

I use `<s:debug /><s:property value="%{#request.base}" />` 
to access `base` attribute in `request`, but nothing shown in my jsp. So why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why do you need this but only `base` inside `request` is inside `.freemarker.TemplateModel` which is `ScopesHashModel`. So you need use method `get` to get things from there.

```
<s:property value="#request['.freemarker.TemplateModel'].get('base')" />
```

Try this:

```
<s:property value="#request['javax.servlet.include.context_path']"/>
```

**Update**

If you just need context path then use `<s:url>` tag for that.

```
<s:url value="/"/>
```

Comment: it did not work. I want to get `contextPath` in jsp, and I find `base` value is just the same as my `contextPath` value. Also I can use `<%=request.getContextPaht()%>`, but I don't like this style, I want to get `contextPath` via OGNL expression.

Comment: no, it does not work either, maybe I am in a wrong direction. It does not support to get `contextPath` via OGNL ?

Comment: @HiwayChe: If you just need context path then use `<s:url>` tag for that. `<s:url value="/" />`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access request parameters following will work

```
<s:property value="#parameters['base']"/>
```

If you want to access attributes of the request then following should work

```
<s:property value="#request.base"/>
```

or

```
<s:property value="#request['base']" />
```

Comment: i've tested the above in Tomcat1.6 running on Java 1.7 and it worked fine. Did anyone come across a scenario where this didn't work ?? Just curious because of the down vote ??