# How to get action url in jsp using Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, request

I have the URL:　http://demo.lendingclub.com/account/summary.action.
When visit this url, it will first go to the ***authenticate interceptor***, in the interceptor class, If I use:

```
String uri = req.getRequestURI();
```

it will return `/account/summary.action`

But if I use it in jsp:

```
<%
    HttpServletRequest req = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    String uri = req.getRequestURI();
%>
```

it will return : `/mainapp/pages/account/summary.jsp`

Why they're different, and how can I get action URL in JSP?

Comment: There's one solution: `String namespace = ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getNamespace();
   String action = ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getName();
   uri = namespace + "/" + action + ".action"; `But I think it's too complicate!!

Comment: `<s:url value="/" />` - http://stackoverflow.com/q/15755583/1700321

Comment: @AleksandrM good one but it can still be shorter ;)

Comment: @Quaternion: Yep, if action url is needed then it should be `<s:url />`.

Comment: I know why they're different:

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to get the current actions url is: `<s:url/>` if you supply namespace and action parameters you can make it point at *other* actions but without these parameters it defaults to the current url.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the action URL or any other value if you set property to the action, and then retrieve that property from the value stack via OGNL.

```
private String actionURL;

public String getActionURL(){
  return actionURL;
}
```

the code to calculate the action URL is similar you posted to the comments

```
public String getPath(){
  ActionProxy proxy = ActionContext.getContext().getActionInvocation().getProxy();
  String namespace =  proxy.getNamespace();
  String name = proxy.getActionName();
  return namespace+(name == null || name.equals("/") ?"":("/"+name));
}
```

this code is not supported `.action` extension, if you need to add the extension to the path then you need to modify this code correspondingly.

then write your action method

```
public String excute() {
   actionURL = getPath();
   ...
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

in the JSP

```
<s:property value="%{actionURL}"/>
```

you have been used dispatcher result to forward request to the JSP as a result you get the URI pointed to the JSP location.